# bundle cannot load such file bundler-1.17.1/exe/bundle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundle, bundler

I had a problem with FileUtils and I had to uninstall the gem. After did this, I did `gem update --default` and some gems have been updated. That fixed my problem with FileUtils but now, bundler is dead.

If I try `bundle info xxx` I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    1: from /Users/robin/.gem/ruby/2.5.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
/Users/robin/.gem/ruby/2.5.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /Users/robin/.rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.1/exe/bundle (LoadError)
```

ruby 2.5.1p57
gem 2.7.7
Rails 5.2.1

I'm using chruby and I have Ruby 2.5.0 and 2.5.1 installed.

I tried to uninstall bundler and reinstall it but that doesn't work.

Now, even if I try `gem install bundler`, there's no directory in the `~/.rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/` folder.

However, I have no error when I install it:

```
gem install bundler
Successfully installed bundler-1.17.1
Parsing documentation for bundler-1.17.1
Done installing documentation for bundler after 3 seconds
1 gem installed
```

Do you have an idea to solve this problem?

**EDIT:**

I can see bundler in my gem list:

`bundler (default: 1.17.1, default: 1.16.2)`

And as you can see, there's two default versions...
Also, I can't find any bundler directory in my gems and if I try to uninstall I get this message:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
    gem "bundler" cannot be uninstalled because it is a default gem
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `gem pristine bundler`, that restores the gem to it's original state.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I get this message : `gem pristine bundler`
`Restoring gems to pristine condition...`
`Skipped bundler-1.16.2, it is a default gem`
`Skipped bundler-1.17.1, it is a default gem`

Comment: uhm, it should restore at least the last version of bundler you have installed.

Try deleting all your ruby versions and chruby, reinstall and then deal with just one version at first.

It's not ideal, but your problem may be that you're using different version binaries for `ruby` and for `gem`.

Comment: Many thanks, I removed all ruby versions and chruby, and I installed rvm instead. Now it works perfectly.