# Gem install the wrong version of bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundle, bundler

I had a problem with Bundler ([bundle cannot load such file bundler-1.17.1/exe/bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53012107/bundle-cannot-load-such-file-bundler-1-17-1-exe-bundle)), so I removed Bundler then manually removed all bundler directory:

`gem uninstall bundler -x`

`gem cleanup bundler`

Then removed with `rm -rf` from:

`~/.gem/ruby/2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.17.1`

`~/.rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.1`

and `~/.bundle`

Now, I would like to reinstall bundler with the default version, 1.17.1.
So I tried `gem install bundler`

```
gem install bundler
Fetching: bundler-1.17.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bundler-1.17.1
Parsing documentation for bundler-1.17.1
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.17.1
Done installing documentation for bundler after 3 seconds
1 gem installed
```

If I try to execute a bundle command, I get this error:

```
bundle
Traceback (most recent call last):
    1: from /Users/robin/.gem/ruby/2.5.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
/Users/robin/.gem/ruby/2.5.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /Users/robin/.rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.1/exe/bundle (LoadError)
```

I can see bundler-1.17.1 in `~/.gem/ruby/2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.17.1` but not in `.rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.1`. So I have to manually copy the folder:

`cp -R  ~/.gem/ruby/2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.17.1 ~/.rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.1`

But now, if I try a bundle command, it works but I have this message in first line:

`Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.16.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.16.6). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running 'gem install bundler'.`

I tried to install bundler by `gem install bundler -v 1.17.1` but I still have the problem.

gem list output:

```
gem list bundler

*** LOCAL GEMS ***
bundler (default: 1.17.1)
capistrano-bundler (1.4.0, 1.3.0)
```

my config:

```
macOS 10.13.6

ruby -v
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-darwin17]

chruby
   ruby-2.5.0
 * ruby-2.5.1

rails -v
Rails 5.2.1

gem -v
2.7.7
```

**EDIT:**

I forgot to specify than `gem pristine bundler` doesn't work with bundler:

```
gem pristine bundler
Restoring gems to pristine condition...
Skipped bundler-1.17.1, it is a default gem
```

And if I try to uninstall bundler twice, I get this message:

```
gem uninstall bundler -x
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
    gem "bundler" cannot be uninstalled because it is a default gem
```

So i don't know if bundler is really uninstalled the first time.

Comment: What is the output of `which bundler`? Is is possible you have another version of the gem being used - e.g. if your `$PATH` includes a local binstub, or you also have gems installed through `rvm`, or something like this?

Comment: Hi @TomLord, `which bundler` returns `/usr/local/bin/bundler`. I don't have `rvm` or another ruby version manager than `chruby`, and I didn't change the `$PATH`

Comment: Well, i removed all ruby versions and chruby and I installed rvm instead. Now it works perfectly. :)